# Web api < is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-authentication

Doing intranet sites, and deployed an ASP.Net Core Web Api to IIS 10.

An api call is reached when Anonymous Authentication is enabled, and everything else is disabled. Which are the default settings in IIS > Authentication.

But when Windows Authentication is enabled and everything else is disabled:
[image]

I get the error:
`'<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.`

Not sure where to look for the problem, or why there even is a problem. Here is the web.config for the site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\webapi.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

**UPDATE**
This is the web api endpoint that I wish to call:

```
        [HttpPost("SaveProduct")]
        public async Task<Product> SaveProduct([FromBody] Product myProduct)
        {
            // some code....
            return myProduct;
        }
```

And this is the calling code in my Blazor app:

```
public async Task SaveProductAync(Product myProduct)
{
    try
    {
        ......
        HttpResponseMessage resp = await new HttpClient().PostAsJsonAsync<Product>("Product/SaveProduct", myProduct, new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web));
        savedProduct = await resp.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Product>();
        ......
    }
}
```

I have a logging class and added a line to log resp.StatusCode, before reading the Content. The code is ***Unauthorized***. So that seems to be the issue, but that was not obvious to me in the error.

When I created the web api project, I chose *No authentication* when creating the project. I wanted to control authentication completely through IIS.

I guess that is not possible? Must I add authentication code to the web api project as well?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the issue but failed. So I believe it's code issue.  I think other api can work well, just that one. So please share the http request details and the code, we can help you.

Comment: @JasonPan thank you for your time, I have added some code.  That suggestion made me put in logging around the calling code to help diagnose, please see the Update section I added.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause for this issue related we are not enable the windows authentication in web application which may cause some error page like 401.

We can verify it by using fiddler or wireshark to capture the http resquest, and check the content of the response.

==============================================================

Thanks for your effort.

Change your code like below, because the return data was in XML instead of JSON. You can add `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");`.

```
@inject HttpClient httpClient

    public async Task SaveProductAync()
    {
        try
        {
            ...
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage resp = await new HttpClient().PostAsJsonAsync<Product>("Product/SaveProduct", myProduct, new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web));
            savedProduct = await resp.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Product>();
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Jason, even with the change, the error still occurs with Windows Auth in the Web Api project.

Comment: Hi @BarnumBailey, Ok, thanks for your effort, I know the reason for your issue after your tried that.

Comment: @BarnumBailey Please use fiddler or other tools to check what the type of return data. It should be html page, like 401. Then we should learn how to enable windows authencation in your project.